# Moving Table of Contents, Search window, Toolbox, etc to second screen?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hardware

Table of Contents, Search, Toolboxes etc. all compete for horizontal space on the computer screen, often obscuring the map display itself.

If I use two screens can I put these windows on one screen and keep my map display on the other?

Comment: Two screens are better than one for everything except moving house.

Comment: Sorry, but going to have to vote to close this as it's primarily opinion-based. However, I will say that I have 3 monitors and it's wonderful. The down side is once you have multiple monitors (esp for years and years), it's _really_ hard to go back to working with one, or even worse, one small one, like a laptop.

Comment: Edited to avoid question being purely opinion based.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25011/using-arcgis-with-dual-multiple-monitors

Comment: Using 2 screens for GIS is already out of fashion. For worldwide datasets, just use a [spherical screen](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=spherical%20screen&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAWoVChMI6Jbz0tSNyQIVyGEOCh0A-wx0&biw=1920&bih=951).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can undock the Catalog, TOC, Toolbox, etc windows and put them on the secondary monitor:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. With both ArcGIS and QGIS.